# Why is prepareForSegue not being called from a UITableViewCell? (Xcode 4.3.3)

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4

In Xcode 4.3.3, I'm attempting to wire up a segue from one story board to another.

I make the connection between the UITableViewCell and my target controller, save changes and deploy to the iPhone simulator.

If I add a break point at the beginning of prepareForSegue, the method is never called when 
I click on the UITableViewCell.

What issues would cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this was quite simple:

- perform a **Clean** on your project
- **Build** and **Run** the app again in the iPhone simulator

I haven't been able to replicate the situation, so I couldn't find out why the updated storyboard Xml file, wasn't getting into the simulator.
If it happens again, I'll post what I found.

Added this for anyone else who has a similar issue.